# How can I pattern match conditionally in a list comprehension in Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, monads

I want to write something like this:

```
> [(i, j) | i <- [1..10], 
            Just j <- [if (even i) then Just (i `div` 2) else Nothing]]
[(2,1),(4,2),(6,3),(8,4),(10,5)]
```

Putting the condition in a list and using `<-` to extract the result seems *ad hoc*.

I tried:

```
> [(i, j) | i <- [1..10], 
            let Just j = if (even i) then Just (i `div` 2) else Nothing]
```

But that failed.

The following works but seems awkward:

```
> [(i, j) | i <- [1..10], 
            let x = if (even i) then Just (i `div` 2) else Nothing, 
            isJust x, 
            let Just j = x]
[(2,1),(4,2),(6,3),(8,4),(10,5)]
```

Is there a preferred way to do this.

*I know this particular problem can be solved in other ways,* but let's assume I want to pattern match conditionally in a list comprehension. ***Is there a good way to do that?***

Thanks.

Comment: From [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "...a *practical*, answerable problem that is unique to software development". What practical reason do you have for needing to do this type of pattern matching in a list comprehension?

Comment: You don't really need pattern matching here. `[(i,div i 2) | i <- [2,4..10]]` would be enough.

Comment: "Putting the condition in a list and using `<-` to extract the result seems ad hoc" would it feel less ad-hoc if instead of `Just j <- [somethingThatReturnsMaybe i]` you wrote `Just j <- return $ somethingThatReturnsMaybe i`?

Comment: This is exactly a question I have @chepner.  I need to write `[x <- xs, y <- ys, Just res@(SomeData (Otherstuff bar _ _ ) _ _ <- somefunc x y,  x == bar]`

Answer (score 2):

Would this be acceptable for you?

```
[(i, j) | i <- [1..10], even i, let j = i `div` 2]
```

Another (IMO worse) option:

```
[(i, j) | i <- [1..10], 
          j <- if even i then [i `div` 2] else []]
```

Yet another:

```
do i <- [1..10]
   j <- guard (even i) >> return (i `div` 2)
   return (i,j)
```

Yet another:

```
[(i, j) | i <- [1..10], 
          j <- [i `div` 2 | even i]]
```

Really overkill and strongly not recommended:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}

testEvenRight :: Integral a => Either b a -> Maybe a
testEvenRight (Right n) | even n = Just n
testEvenRight _                  = Nothing

pattern EvenRight n <- (testEvenRight -> Just n)

list1 = [Right 2, Right 1, Left "abc", Right 4, Right 5]

list2 = [(i,j) | EvenRight i <- list1 , let j = i `div` 2]
```

Comment: Where is the pattern match in that?

Comment: @Thilo There is none, since there's no need to. I wonder what the OP _really_ needs, since this looks as an XY problem.

Comment: Maybe it is, but he states that "this particular problem can be solved in other ways, but let's assume I want to pattern match conditionally in a list comprehension".

Comment: Exactly! The question was about whether there is a good way to use pattern matching in a list comprehension. It was not about this particular problem, which just illustrated how pattern matching might be used. I explicitly pointed out that I wasn't interested in solutions to this particular problem exactly because I was afraid I would get answers like these. It didn't seem to help!

Comment: @RussAbbott I think I now understand what you don't want, but I still have little ideas about what you do want. Do you want a statement like "No, you can't use guards in pattern matching in list comprehensions" ? I am a bit puzzled. The closest you can get to patterns with guards is shown above in my answer as the last alternative. Not convenient at all.